# How often is Google Patents updated?

Tags: patent-search

Or, how long after an application is published by the USPTO is it included in the Google Patent database?

For example, as of today, 2014-11-12, the most recent utility application was published 2014-11-06 (US20140331368).  It looks like the most recent application available on Google was published 2014-10-09 (US20140304863), which would make it at least 4 weeks.

The [Google Patents help page](http://support.google.com/faqs/answer/2539193) just says that it covers the "entire collection". No clarification on the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Patents) either.

Comment: I just looked for us20140304963 on some other sites and found it at lens.org, freepatents online and at the EPO's Espacenet. Google patents has many pluses but it is not as quick to add the newest documents.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen Since Google Patents is a common tool used in this subject space, technical questions about its use seem reasonably on-topic here. But our scope would *not* include "Google customer service" issues like database problems, bug reports, feature requests (for Google Patents) because those would have to be asked of the Google folks with whom we have no affiliation.

Comment: I realize that this question was a bit of a stretch in regards to the scope of the site - perhaps better asked in meta. 

I did follow up on [Google Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/websearch/bnMrPupmQWg/FSqSE8cJdQEJ), but no useful answer yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, Google updates their database every other month and the data they input in their database are a couple of months late. It is still best that you search for patents in the USPTO or in other patent databases that are more regularly updated than Google patents.