# My patent is pending and it was just published in the UK Ipsum, when it will appear in Google Patents?

Tags: publication

My patent is pending and they advised it will be finally granted in October 2020. However, it was published last week. When should I expect the full text to appear in Google Patents and ESPACENET? Also, when do patents appear in Google after a PCT filling took place?

Comment: [Google suggests][1] that coverage dates for each of the patent offices can be found by clicking on "from around the world" on the Google Patents home page.  For the UK, the abbreviation is GB.  However, when I tried this today and yesterday, for the US it indicates "Full-text since: no full text available".  I have sent "Feedback" to Google using the link at the bottom of the screen.  


  [1]: https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7049585?hl=en

Comment: This question is related, but also lacks a satisfying and current answer: https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/10572/how-often-is-google-patents-updated

Answer (score 1):

Only Google can tell you, but I did an experiment. I searched on [patents.google.com](https://patents.google.com/?after=publication:20200501&status=APPLICATION&type=PATENT&sort=new) for the most recent publication of patent applications. The date of the search is June 8th, 2020 and the most recent publications listed was a Korean application for May 27th, 2020. Next most recent were Australian publications on May 14th, 2020. The most recent EP was May 13th, 2020. It looks like it might depend on the country when an update is done and it might take several weeks at least.

I did a similar search on [The Lens](https://www.lens.org/lens/search?n=10&q=&dates=%2Bpub_date:20200501-20200608&l=en&st=true&preview=true&p=0&s=pub_date&d=-) and the newest publications were for May 14th, 2020 and were primarily German.